# Adding or subtracting to fields in Access

Tags: ms-access, addition, subtraction

Is there a way to take out or add some amount to a numerical field in Access without manually changing the value?

Comment: There is much info about SQL UPDATE if you search.

Comment: Could you improve this question to add more context? It's not really clear what you really want to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an [UPDATE query](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/update-data-by-using-a-query-HA010076527.aspx).  For example:

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET MyNumField = MyNumField + 5
```